# Blazor WASM Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically. Move the script tag to the index.html file

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a `.Net 6` `Blazor Wasm` app. I need to place `<script type="application/ld+json">` inside each landing page component for `SEO` benefits.

I'm already making use of `<HeadContent>` to add other `<meta>` and `<link>` tags. So I decided to use the same component for this purpose.

However when I place the `<script>` tag inside `<HeadContent>`, I'm getting the compilation error as follows,

> Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot
> be updated dynamically. To fix this, move the script tag to the
> 'index.html' file or another static location.

To workaround this issue, I added my script tag as string text inside `<HeadContent>` as shown below,

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<HeadContent>
   @($@"<script type=""application/ld+json"">
        {{
            ""@context"": ""https://schema.org"",
            ""@type"": ""WebSite"",
            ""publisher"": {{
                ""@type"": ""Organization"",
                ""name"": ""Page Name"",
                ""url"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}"",
                ""logo"": {{
                    ""@type"": ""ImageObject"",
                    ""url"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}favicon.ico"",
                    ""width"": 16,
                    ""height"": 16
                }}
            }},
            ""url"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}"",
            ""mainEntityOfPage"": {{
                ""@type"": ""WebPage"",
                ""@id"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}""
            }},
            ""description"": ""some good description about the page""
        }}
    </script>")
</HeadContent>
```

But this renders the script as text inside head tag in browser as shown in below screenshot:

[image: Rendered HeadContent]

Will this affect `SEO` benefits or is there any better way to handle this? Please assist.

Comment: There's no `HEAD` in a component. You're building an SPA, just like React, and the entire application is essentially scripts loaded in `index.html`. You *can't* modify the page's `HEAD` after the fact to automagically load scripts. What you did was emit a tag the browser doesn't recognize so it just rendered it as-is. WebAssembly doesn't change JavaScript's rules. You can `import` modules though, at least in Blazor 6.

Comment: script tag of type `application/ld+json` will get executed in browser? Even in the case of importing do I need to add the script tag in head after the component has been rendered? Please can you explain more?

Comment: try `@(new MarkupString( ... ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering a string not markup.

```
@(new MarkupString($@"<script type=""application/ld+json"">
        {{
            ""@context"": ""https://schema.org"",
            ""@type"": ""WebSite"",
            ""publisher"": {{
                ""@type"": ""Organization"",
                ""name"": ""Page Name"",
                ""url"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}"",
                ""logo"": {{
                    ""@type"": ""ImageObject"",
                    ""url"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}favicon.ico"",
                    ""width"": 16,
                    ""height"": 16
                }}
            }},
            ""url"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}"",
            ""mainEntityOfPage"": {{
                ""@type"": ""WebPage"",
                ""@id"": ""{NavigationManager.BaseUri}""
            }},
            ""description"": ""some good description about the page""
        }}
    </script>"))
```

Answer (score 21):

If you are sure you know what you are doing and want to use a script tag - and will test thoroughly - you can override the warning like this

```html
<script suppress-error="BL9992">...</script>
```

In this case, as your `script` contains json it may be ok