# Define text/template script in Blazor component

Tags: html, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, script-tag

I need some templated markup inside my blazor component.

This is how I'd typically define it (and read it via script):

```html
<script type="text/template" id="foo">
  ...
</script>
```

However that gives:

> Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically. To fix this, move the script tag to the 'index.html' file or another static location. (RZ9992)

How can I suppress `RZ9992` just for that one code block?

UPDATE: no that supposed dupe is far more complicated that what I wanted here. People who want a template tag will get the same error, but for a different problem.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670071/blazor-wasm-script-tags-should-not-be-placed-inside-components-because-they-cann

Comment: @NevilleNazerane It's not a duplicate, that question simply suffers from the same compiler error. I specifically want template text. And most searchers for my problem will land here.

Comment: Ok i'll just leave the link here for others to decide. The highly voted answer in that link is similar to your answer. Also, most people look up issues by looking up the error message, which leads us to the other question.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're putting into the script tag?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Many things, really. For example, today I used this approach to store the template used in a bootstrap popover. But I've since changed to using `<template>` instead which avoids this problem altogether, and according to caniuse, seems widely supported these days.

Comment: NP.  I saw your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13917#issuecomment-531246747).

```html
<script type="text/template" id="foo" suppress-error="BL9992">
  ...
</script>
```

But there's an even better way, which according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/template) is widely supported now:

```html
<template id="foo">
  ...
</template>
```

However, note that (<strike>probably due to  [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45605)</strike> by [design](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45605#issuecomment-1353409330)) the tag will be empty if it contains a component:

```html
<template id="foo">
  <MyComponent />
</template>
```